# Python: how to set a different output folder

Tags: python, arcpy, workspace

I want to transform some vectors to rasters in my folder but I have difficulties setting the output folder. The following code only allows me to output to the original database. I hope to output all results to the same folder instead of in their original database.

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = "D:\Jiawei default download"
feature_classes = []
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    if "Subbasin" in filenames:
        filenames.remove('Subbasin')
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print feature_classes

for item in feature_classes[98:]:
   inFeatures = item
   valField = "wtdepaprjunmin"
   outRaster = item+"_r"
   print "processing "+item
# Execute PolygonToRaster
   arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(inFeatures, valField, outRaster)
```

Comment: Remember to escape your backslashes. The workspace above should be workspace = "D:\\Jiawei default download"

Answer (score 2):

You set a workspace, so any outputs from the script will default to that location unless you explicitly put them somewhere else.  Create a folder for the outputs, then write your output rasters to that folder.

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = "D:\Jiawei default download"
feature_classes = []
outputFolder = r'c:\outputfolder'
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    if "Subbasin" in filenames:
        filenames.remove('Subbasin')
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print feature_classes

for item in feature_classes[98:]:
   inFeatures = item
   valField = "wtdepaprjunmin"
   outRaster = outputFolder+item+"_r"
   print "processing "+item
# Execute PolygonToRaster
   arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(inFeatures, valField, outRaster)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems easy enough but it gave me error message "ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function." Trying to figure out

Comment: Print your `outRaster` variable...  I think you'll find it to be an invalid path.  Using `os.path.join()` like you did earlier is really the best way to construct paths.

Comment: Then what should I do to change output location?

Comment: Well, because `item` looks like it'll be a full path to a feature class (not sure if it's in a gdb or if it's a shapefile), you need to pull just the basename of it, and then you need to decide what format you want the raster to be in.  Because your out folder is not a geodatabase, I'd recommend creating tiffs.  So: `outRaster = os.path.join(outputFolder,os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(item))[0]+".tif")` would probably do it.  But, start by printing the variable, then read up on `os.path.basename` and `os.path.splitext`... that's where I'd recommend starting at least.